# Open Graph error code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm testing the open-graph with the tutorial, but I keep getting 
"API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: The app must have aggregation units with sample data in order to request the publish_actions permission"

URL: http://spimegen.appspot.com/

any idea..?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go into your Open Graph settings for your app. Go to Aggregations. Click on "Preview" for your aggregation units. If any of your aggregation units come up empty (no actions/objects shown), add sample objects and sample actions. Once you've added sample objects and actions, you won't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

if you're requesting the `publish_actions` permission one of the following must be true (as of Oct 2011)

1. Your app is in the games category, and you're using the permission for [Achievements API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) or [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/scores/)
2. You're testing the [Open Graph Beta](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/) APIs, and you've defined actions, objects and a timeline aggregation for your app.

Comment: Could you possibly be more specific about how to create the sample data for the aggregation units (which you referred to as the timeline unit)?  I've used the interface to create a Preview Object and tried to create a Preview Action, but I get the message: Something went wrong.  We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.  I entered numeric ids for sample place, tag, photo, and my object type.

Comment: I"m not sure, that could be a bug if it's happening for you consistently

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I've also added an action, and object, and an aggregation, but get error #100. The dialogs are pretty confusing though. Even though I entered some sample data in the object, there isn't a proper preview of the aggregation with the sample data, suggesting that the sample data didn't propagate from the object to the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I am also hosting my app on the google app engine and experiencing the same 100.
**UPDATE:** Jeff Sherlock's answer did it for me. So it's not app engine related. : ] Thanks!

Comment: this would be a comment on the question, but I do not have enough reputation :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error. I've also added an action, and object, and an aggregation, but get error #100. The dialogs are pretty confusing though. Even though I entered some sample data in the object, there isn't a proper preview of the aggregation with the sample data, suggesting that the sample data didn't propagate from the object to the aggregation. –
Garth
Oct 17, 2011 at 4:10